# Retrieving object.class.simpleName returns "Object_$$_jvst622_7"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thymeleaf

I'm working on a Spring Boot project using Thymeleaf for the templates.

In my entities, I have 2 sub classes that extend an abstract class.

In my Html file, when I'm trying to display the name of the sub class. The name generated with Thymeleaf is not correct.

For example, it displays : "Compte_$$_jvst622_7" instead of the name of the subclass.

```
<label th:text="${compte.class.simpleName}"></label>
```

the incorrect result displayed in the Html view is :Compte_$$_jvst622_7

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was able to resolve my problem ... Actually it was not a Thymeleaf problem : in my service, I was accessing my entity with the method getOne(String id) from JpaRepository :

```
Compte cp = compteRepository.getOne(codeCpte);
```

Which seems to not get the exact object I wanted so the name of the class was not the same and the specifics attributes or methods of this object couldn't be found.

So instead, I used the method findById(String Id) which return an Optional :

```
Optional<Compte> cp = compteRepository.findById(codeCpte);
```

Hope it can help if someone gets the same issue.